# docker container with no ip

Tags: docker, rancher

Here is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '2'

services:
  app:
    image: mykiwi/ttrss

  database:
    image: postgres:10-alpine
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=ttrss
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=ttrss
    volumes:
      - database:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  database: ~
```

But when I inspect my main container, there is no ip address:

```
$ docker inspect 40f78d12c178
...
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "70479dc6e987e744e376f6e4222e8d26174b724b686da52924a7e539ef4d4f0c",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {},
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/70479dc6e987",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "",
            "Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "",
            "IPPrefixLen": 0,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "",
            "Networks": {
                "none": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "NetworkID": "2c6c546b04398c4b4c7b9e52fdb16b89aacfea33b9038b6aa90b4b44fbd99ac7",
                    "EndpointID": "ac4da8b1b38118732a6e9e99a0ba56b271e6810afd78975c5f329185cf047bf7",
                    "Gateway": "",
                    "IPAddress": "",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 0,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

I run it through rancher, is it related ?

Answer (score 1):

Rancher uses CNI drivers for networking and so the network is "none" as far as Docker is concerned and no IP addresses or port info appears in Docker inspect.  You can get it from the metadata service.

Comment: Ok. I use Traefik in front, and access to container through it and the docker backend. Should I set a rancher backend too? Because without container ip I can't access them like I do with basic docker containers